# download http source using httpclient async task

Tags: c#, httpclient

trying to download/get page html source using the code below found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall

trying to learn and very new. i have tried to modify few things here and there, which didnt work.

```
    private async void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
    {  
        resultsTextBox.Clear();  

        // One-step async call.  
        await SumPageSizesAsync();  

        // Two-step async call.  
        //Task sumTask = SumPageSizesAsync();  
        //await sumTask;  

        resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nControl returned to startButton_Click.\r\n";  
    }  

    private async Task SumPageSizesAsync()  
    {  
        // Make a list of web addresses.  
        List<string> urlList = SetUpURLList();  

        // Declare an HttpClient object and increase the buffer size. The  
        // default buffer size is 65,536.  
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };  

        // Create a query.  
        IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery =   
            from url in urlList select ProcessURLAsync(url, client);  

        // Use ToArray to execute the query and start the download tasks.  
        Task<int>[] downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToArray();  

        // You can do other work here before awaiting.  

        // Await the completion of all the running tasks.  
        int[] lengths = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);  

        //// The previous line is equivalent to the following two statements.  
        //Task<int[]> whenAllTask = Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);  
        //int[] lengths = await whenAllTask;  

        int total = lengths.Sum();  

        //var total = 0;  
        //foreach (var url in urlList)  
        //{  
        //    // GetByteArrayAsync returns a Task<T>. At completion, the task  
        //    // produces a byte array.  
        //    byte[] urlContent = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);  

        //    // The previous line abbreviates the following two assignment  
        //    // statements.  
        //    Task<byte[]> getContentTask = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);  
        //    byte[] urlContent = await getContentTask;  

        //    DisplayResults(url, urlContent);  

        //    // Update the total.  
        //    total += urlContent.Length;  
        //}  

        // Display the total count for all of the web addresses.  
        resultsTextBox.Text +=  
            $"\r\n\r\nTotal bytes returned:  {total}\r\n";
    }  

    private List<string> SetUpURLList()  
    {  
        List<string> urls = new List<string>   
        {   
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290136.aspx",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee256749.aspx",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290138.aspx",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd470362.aspx",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx",  
            "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx"  
        };  
        return urls;  
    }  

    // The actions from the foreach loop are moved to this async method.  
    async Task<int> ProcessURLAsync(string url, HttpClient client)  
    {  
        byte[] byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);  
        DisplayResults(url, byteArray);  
        return byteArray.Length;  
    }  

    private void DisplayResults(string url, byte[] content)  
    {  
        // Display the length of each web site. The string format   
        // is designed to be used with a monospaced font, such as  
        // Lucida Console or Global Monospace.  
        var bytes = content.Length;  
        // Strip off the "https://".  
        var displayURL = url.Replace("https://", "");  
        resultsTextBox.Text += $"\n{displayURL,-58} {bytes,8}";
    }
```

**EDIT -**

this code is from the link i posted, i tested the code, it returns byte/length of the content. but i would like the page source instead of byte/length information. i tried by changing the processurlasync function and was able to get html source. but is this the right way to do it and most efficient way to do it?

```
    async Task<int> ProcessURLAsync(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        //DisplayResults(url, byteArray);
        return byteArray.Length;
    }
    async Task<string> ProcessURLAsyncS(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        var byteArrayS = new StreamReader(await client.GetStreamAsync(url));
        //byte[] byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        DisplayResults(url, byteArrayS.ReadToEnd());
        return byteArrayS.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What does it do? What did you expect it to do differently? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: It might help to read [ask] and [mcve] . "Didn't work" is not a useful description, we need details.

Comment: You're saying it didn't work, that ultimately you're trying to download the HTML source. But it's up to you to described *how* it failed. What values did you get? What exception(s) were thrown, if any? Did it say how many bytes were returned?

Comment: I was trying to help you.  If you think your question is sufficient as written, that's fine, but I disagree and don't consider it likely you'll receive an adequate answer.  We are commenting on your question in an effort to help you.

Comment: I agree the question is poorly written, but I think I was able to provide some useful guidance in my answer below.  In the future, please try to limit your question to a specific point - which I think was something like "How do I retrieve the content as a string using HttpClient?"

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- If you want the make a `GET` request and read the content as a string, then just use [`GetStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync):

  ```
  string content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
  ```
- Be careful about reading the entire content in one string.  That might be lot of memory to consume.  The reason to use `GetStreamAsync` instead would be to read from the stream in chunks and write that output elsewhere.
- The example code sample you cited is quite old, and makes some mistakes:

  1. The [default buffer size is 2GB](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.maxresponsecontentbuffersize), not 64KB.  There's no need to set it explicitly in most cases.
  2. [`HttpClient` is meant to be created as a single instance and shared](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), not created for each request (or for each click of the button in this case).
  3. The line that calls `downloadTasksQuery.ToArray()` is unnecessary.  Once you start awaiting tasks, they will start.